# How to optimize the 3 conditions if else if Statements

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

Hi i have to check the three conditions, is there any Way to optimize the code other than the if else if statements. if i am checking all the three combinations its going to more lines of code do we have any better option to check all the conditions. Please can anybody help me on this to optimize the code.

```
if (req.body.officeId === "null" && req.body.branchId === "null" && req.body.productId === "null") {
  updatedTestData = _.omit(req.body, ['officeId', 'branchId', 'roomId']);
  updatedTestData.officeId = null;
  updatedTestData.office = {};
  updatedTestData.branchId = null;
  updatedTestData.branch = {};
  updatedTestData.productId = null;
  updatedTestData.product = {};

} else if (req.body.officeId === "null" && req.body.branchId === "null" && !req.body.productId === "null") {
  updatedTestData = _.omit(req.body, ['officeId', 'branchId']);
  updatedTestData.officeId = null;
  updatedTestData.office = {};
  updatedTestData.branchId = null;
  updatedTestData.branch = {};

}
```

Comment: I don't think you want to do `!req.body.productId === "null"`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var condition = [ req.body.officeId, req.body.branchId, req.body.productId]

if (condition.every(item => item === "null") { 

   // do some work

} 

if (condition.every(item => item !== "null") {

  // do other work

}
```

`every` will automatically exit if it finds a `false` value, so you will only have to go through your conditions until they fail.

Comment: The OP's code does nothing if either req.body.officeId or req.body.branchId are non-null. That is not the case with your code as the second block will get executed if all 3 are non-null.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly better version:

```
if(req.body.officeId === "null" && req.body.branchId === "null"){
    if(req.body.productId === "null"){
        //your first code block
    }else{
        //your second code block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
if (req.body.officeId === "null" && req.body.branchId === "null") {

    if (req.body.productId === "null"){
        updatedTestData = _.omit(req.body, ['officeId', 'branchId', 'roomId']);
        updatedTestData.officeId = null;
        updatedTestData.office = {};
        updatedTestData.branchId = null;
        updatedTestData.branch = {};
        updatedTestData.productId = null;
        updatedTestData.product = {};
        return
    }

    updatedTestData = _.omit(req.body, ['officeId', 'branchId']);
    updatedTestData.officeId = null;
    updatedTestData.office = {};
    updatedTestData.branchId = null;
    updatedTestData.branch = {};


}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 of the checks are common to both the if and elseif so you could extract those to an outer if...

```
if (req.body.officeId === "null" && req.body.branchId === "null") {
  if (req.body.productId === "null") {
    updatedTestData = _.omit(req.body, ['officeId', 'branchId', 'roomId']);
    updatedTestData.officeId = null;
    updatedTestData.office = {};
    updatedTestData.branchId = null;
    updatedTestData.branch = {};
    updatedTestData.productId = null;
    updatedTestData.product = {};
  } else {
    updatedTestData = _.omit(req.body, ['officeId', 'branchId']);
    updatedTestData.officeId = null;
    updatedTestData.office = {};
    updatedTestData.branchId = null;
    updatedTestData.branch = {};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['officeId', 'branchId'];
var body = req.body;
var office = body.officeId;
var branch= body.branchId;
var product= body.productId;
if(office === 'null' && branch === 'null') {
    if(product !== 'null') {
        array.push('roomId');
        updatedTestData = _.omit(body, array);
        testChange(body, 'product', updatedTestData); 
    } else {

    }
}

testChange(req.body, 'office', updatedTestData);
testChange(req.body, 'branch', updatedTestData);

function testChange(object, key, toChange) {
    if(object[key] === 'null') {
        toChange[key + 'Id'] = null;
        toChange[key] = {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach in ES 5:

```
var isNull = function(items) { 
       if (items === null) return true;
       if (items.length) { 
               return  items.reduce(
                           function(p, c){
                             return ((c===null) && p);
                           }, true); 
       }

       return false;
}

if (isNull([req.body.officeId, 
                 req.body.branchId, 
                 req.body.productId]))  
{
   //
}
else if (isNull([req.body.officeId, 
                 req.body.branchId] && !isNull(req.body.productId))
{
   //
}
```